# Add multiple users to node JS env file

Tags: node.js, authentication, environment-variables, node-modules

I have a nodeJS application. In the .env file I have specified

```
AUTH_USERNAME=admin
AUTH_PASSWORD=password
```

I now want to add separate admin accounts for more users. What is the best/accepted way to attack this? I have tried searching on the topic but, understandably, it gets very complicated very quickly - can anyone give me a dummies guide for my possibilities here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in your case without changing approach where to store credentials is use separator in environment variables. Example with `,` as separator:

```
#.env file or environment variables values
AUTH_USERNAMES=admin,admin2
AUTH_PASSWORDS=password,password2


//your code
require('dotenv').config(); // for reading .env file or how do you use that
const adminsUsernames = process.env.AUTH_USERNAMES.split(',');
const adminsPasswords = process.env.AUTH_PASSWORDS.split(',');
```

Please, think about change `.env` file to database or `config.json` file. Maybe, this list will help you:

- obviously,  you received downvotes on your question, because of non-common approach where to store credentials. Common approach is store credentials at database.
- according [The Twelve Factors manifest](https://12factor.net/config) environment variables are
  used for configuration whole application.
- `.env` is used for simplification setting environment variables during local development. In production DevOps setup env vars on the server.